# getting source scene from menuItem

Tags: events, javafx, scene

I found related questions on the side, but no without using FXML, `MenuItem` doesn't have a super class that I can cast down to get the scene. I use the below approach when I found the same problem with a button instance.

```
(Scene) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene();
```

I any ideas on how to solve this issue will be most appreciated. 
Thanks In advance

here is the window's view

```
/**
 * @author Jose Gonzalez
 *
 */
 public class Transaction  extends TempletePattern{
  private ImageView viewImage;
  private Button button;
  private TransactionController controller;
  private TableView<Saving> table;
  private TableColumn dateColum;
  private TableColumn descriptionColum;
  private TableColumn amountColum;
  private TableColumn valanceColum;
  /**
   * 
   * @param controller
   */
  public Transaction(TransactionController controller)
  {
    this.controller = controller;

  }

/**
 * main method all private methods in the class and set them up on the        borderpane
 * @return pane fully setup to be mount on the scene
 */
public BorderPane setScreen() 
{

    BorderPane trans = new BorderPane();
    trans.setStyle("-fx-background: #FFFFFF;");
    VBox topBox = new VBox ();
    topBox.getChildren().addAll( setMenu(),setTop() );
    trans.setTop(topBox );
    trans.setBottom(processUpdate(process) );
    trans.setCenter(setCenter() );


    return trans;
}
/**
 * 
 * @return vbox holding all note pertaining to the center of the borderpane
 */
private VBox setCenter()
{

    VBox center = new VBox();
    center.setPadding(new Insets(30, 20, 20, 20) );
    table = new TableView<>();
    table.setEditable(true);

    dateColum = new TableColumn("Date");
    dateColum.setCellValueFactory( new PropertyValueFactory<>("firstName"));
    dateColum.prefWidthProperty().bind(table.widthProperty().divide(4));
    dateColum.setResizable(false);

    descriptionColum = new TableColumn("Description");
    descriptionColum.prefWidthProperty().bind(table.widthProperty().divide(4));
    descriptionColum.setResizable(false);
    descriptionColum.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("lastName") );

    amountColum = new TableColumn("Amount");
    amountColum.prefWidthProperty().bind(table.widthProperty().divide(4));
    amountColum.setResizable(false);
    amountColum.setCellValueFactory( new PropertyValueFactory<>("transaction") );

    valanceColum = new TableColumn("Availble Valance");
    valanceColum.prefWidthProperty().bind(table.widthProperty().divide(4));
    valanceColum.setResizable(false);
    valanceColum.setCellValueFactory( new PropertyValueFactory<>("valance"));

    table.getColumns().addAll(dateColum, descriptionColum, amountColum,valanceColum );
    mockInfo();
    center.getChildren().add(table);

    return center;
}

/**
 * 
 * @return the screen's menu fully set up
 */
private MenuBar setMenu()
{

    MenuBar menubar = new MenuBar();
     final Menu UserMenu = new Menu("User");
     UserMenu.setId("user");
     UserMenu.setOnAction(controller);
     MenuItem itemLog = new MenuItem("log out");
     itemLog.setId("logout");
     itemLog.setOnAction(controller);
     MenuItem itemAcount = new MenuItem("new acount");
     itemAcount.setId("newAccount");
     UserMenu.getItems().addAll(itemLog, itemAcount);

     final Menu acctMenu = new Menu("Accounts");
     MenuItem itemsavis = new MenuItem("Savings");
     MenuItem itemCredit = new MenuItem("Credit");
     MenuItem itemChecking = new MenuItem("Checking");
     acctMenu.getItems().addAll(itemsavis, itemCredit, itemChecking);


     final Menu aboutMenu = new Menu("about");
     MenuItem itemHelp = new MenuItem("Help");
     aboutMenu.getItems().addAll(itemHelp);


     menubar.getMenus().addAll(UserMenu,  acctMenu, aboutMenu);

    return menubar;
}

/**
 * @param receive constumer info from model through controller and set it on table.
 */
public void  tableDataSetter(ObservableList<Saving> costumerInfo)
{
    table.setItems(costumerInfo);
}

/**
 * insert mock data to be displayed as a place holder 
 */
private void  mockInfo()
{

    ObservableList<Saving> data =
            FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                    new Saving("11/10/16", "Deposit", 123, "123" ),
                    new Saving("11/11/16", "Withdraw", 5, "123" ),
                    new Saving("11/12/16", "Deposit", 24, "123" ),
                    new Saving("11/13/16", "Withdraw", 62, "123" ),
                    new Saving("11/14/16", "Deposit", 134, "123" ),
                    new Saving("11/15/16", "Deposit", 134, "123" ), 
                    new Saving("11/10/16", "Withdraw", 123, "123" ),
                    new Saving("11/11/16", "Deposit", 5, "123" ),
                    new Saving("11/12/16", "Withdraw", 24, "123" ),
                    new Saving("11/13/16", "Deposit", 62, "123" ),
                    new Saving("11/14/16", "Withdraw", 134, "123" ),
                    new Saving("11/15/16", "Deposit", 134, "123" ) 
                    );

    table.setItems(  data  );
 }



}
```

and here is the controller. ps I just started working on it.

```
public class TransactionController implements EventHandler{


    //private LoginModel model ;
    private Transaction view;


    public TransactionController()
   {
    //  model = new  LoginModel();
        view = new Transaction(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(Event event) {

        if( (  event.getSource() instanceof MenuItem))
        {
            System.out.println( "afe   " +   (((Object)event.getTarget()))   );
            if(  ( (MenuItem) (event.getSource())  ).getId().equals("logout")  )
            {

                System.err.println("from inside logout");
            /// this.goTologInt(event);
            }else if( ( (MenuItem) (event.getSource())  ).getId().equals("newAccount")  )
            {
            //  this.goToNewAct(event);

            }


        }

    }

    private void goToNewAct(Event event)
    {
        Scene scene =  (Scene) ( (Control) event.getSource()).getScene();
     //   Stage stage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        NewCustomerView  newAcct = new NewCustomerView();
       scene.setRoot( newAcct.newCustomerScreen()); 
    }


    private void goTologInt(Event event)
    {
        Scene scene = (Scene)   ((Node)event.getSource()).getScene()  ;
        //Scene scene =  (Scene) ((Control) event.getSource()).getScene();
      //  Stage stage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        LoginView  newAcct = new LoginView( new LoginController());
       scene.setRoot( newAcct.loginScreen()); 
    }

}
```

Comment: It's hard to imagine a scenario where you are adding a handler to a menu item in a context where you can't get the scene, or at least a node in the scene, reasonably easily. Can you give some context for this, e.g. a [MCVE] showing why you need to get the scene *solely* from the event?

Comment: on my application I want to give the user the ability to add a new account. The plan it to get the user to another screen/pane without creating  a new stage or scene.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question though. In the code where you register the handler, you must be able to get a reference either to the scene, or to something in the scene. Can you [edit] your question and post some code *with sufficient context* to show the problem?

Comment: I apologize for not posting the example ahead of time. To the point, yes, you  would expect to be able to get some type of useful reference from the even, but I haven't been successful at it.

Answer (score 0):

You could go up through the menu hierarchy until you reach a menu with a popup and get the owner window of this popup, which is the window the context menu was opened from.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem("Something");
    Menu menuInner = new Menu("menu", null, menuItem);
    Menu menuOuter = new Menu("menu", null, menuInner);
    MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar(menuOuter);

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT);
    root.getChildren().add(menuBar);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    menuItem.setOnAction(evt -> {
        MenuItem m = (MenuItem) evt.getSource();
        while (m.getParentPopup() == null) {
            m = m.getParentMenu();
        }

        Scene s = m.getParentPopup().getOwnerWindow().getScene();
        System.out.println(s == scene);
    });

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

---

In general I'd consider it a better idea though to simply make the information about the scene in question available to the `EventHandler` of the `MenuItem`:

```
final Scene scene = ...

menuItem.setOnAction(evt -> {
    // do something with scene
});
```

The alternative to a (effectively) `final` local variable would be using a field...

Comment: Thank you, Fabian your answer certainly works. I tried going up the menu hierarchy a couple of times, but my approach was incorrect. I am purposely not passing the scene around. I want to avoid coupling issues or just simple see whether  the program can be done without passing the scene.